# Assembly on Minix

Tags: assembly, x86, minix

I've installed Minix 3 in VMWare on Windows7 64 bit.  I'm trying to practice assembly on this VM.  Just to start out, I tried a simple program to load numbers into eax and ebx and call the o/s to terminate the program.

```
.globl _start:
.section .text
_start:
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

the compiler and linker don't raise any errors or warnings, but when i run the executable, i get

```
PM: coredump signal 11 for 282 / <program name>
memory fault
```

Is this caused by the host being a 64 bit machine?  is it because minix has a different o/s call?  i've tried searching around the net specifically for minix o/s calls, and I found solutions to particular o/s calls, but no table of o/s calls.  can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: I guess you mean "different system calls from i386 Linux", because that's where int 0x80 / eax=1 will invoke `sys_exit`.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

**minix-exit.S**

```
  .section .text
  .global _start
_start:
  /* _exit(17) */
  and $0xfffffff0, %esp
  sub $0x40, %esp
  movl $17, 0x18(%esp) /* exit status */
  lea 0x10(%esp), %ebx
  movl $1, 0x04(%ebx)  /* EXIT in include/minix/callnr.h */
  movl $0, %eax        /* PM_PROC_NR in include/minix/com.h */
  movl $0x3, %ecx      /* SENDREC in include/minix/ipcconst.h */
  int $33              /* IPCVEC_ORIG in sys/arch/i386/include/asm.h */
```

Build and run with:

```
$ clang -nostdlib minix-exit.S -o minix-exit
$ ./minix-exit; echo $?
17
```

I find the easiest way to figuring out Minix 3's syscall implementation is to do a bit of reverse engineering before reading the code:

### Calling Sequence

Minix, being a micro kernel, insists on structuring syscalls as messages you can send to different managers. `exit()` is implemented by sending `EXIT` to `PM_PROC_NR`:

- `_exit(status)` (in [lib/libc/sys-minix/_exit.c](https://github.com/Stichting-MINIX-Research-Foundation/minix/blob/v3.2.1/lib/libc/sys-minix/_exit.c))

  - `_syscall(PM_PROC_NR, EXIT, msg)` (in [lib/libc/sys-minix/syscall.c](https://github.com/Stichting-MINIX-Research-Foundation/minix/blob/v3.2.1/lib/libc/sys-minix/syscall.c))

    - `_sendrec_orig(PM_PROC_NR, msg)`
                  (in [lib/libc/arch/i386/sys-minix/_ipc.S](https://github.com/Stichting-MINIX-Research-Foundation/minix/blob/v3.2.1/lib/libc/arch/i386/sys-minix/_ipc.S#L24))

### Figuring this out by a bit of Reverse Engineering

Look at how a simple statically linked executable like `/bin/cat` implements `_exit()` on Minix.

**dis.gdb**

```
set pagination 0

file /bin/cat
set logging on
disassemble _exit
disassemble _syscall
x/a 0x8072678
disassemble _sendrec_orig
quit
```

Run:

```
gdb -q -x dis.gdb
```

### GDB Output

```
Dump of assembler code for function _exit:
0x0805b780 :   push   %ebp
0x0805b781 :   mov    %esp,%ebp
0x0805b783 :   and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x0805b789 :   sub    $0x40,%esp
0x0805b78c :  mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0805b78f :  mov    %eax,0x18(%esp)
0x0805b793 :  lea    0x10(%esp),%eax
0x0805b797 :  mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x0805b79b :  movl   $0x1,0x4(%esp)
0x0805b7a3 :  movl   $0x0,(%esp)
0x0805b7aa :  call   0x805dfc0 
0x0805b7af :  call   0x805b7af 
0x0805b7b4 :  nopw   %cs:0x0(%eax,%eax,1)
0x0805b7c0 :  jmp    0x805b7c0 
End of assembler dump.
Dump of assembler code for function syscall:
0x0805dfc0 : push   %ebp
0x0805dfc1 : mov    %esp,%ebp
0x0805dfc3 : push   %esi
0x0805dfc4 : sub    $0xc,%esp
0x0805dfc7 : mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x0805dfca :    mov    0x10(%ebp),%esi
0x0805dfcd :    mov    %eax,0x4(%esi)
0x0805dfd0 :    mov    %esi,0x4(%esp)
0x0805dfd4 :    mov    0x8(%ebp),%ecx
0x0805dfd7 :    mov    %ecx,(%esp)
0x0805dfda :    call   *0x8072678
0x0805dfe0 :    test   %eax,%eax
0x0805dfe2 :    je     0x805dfe9 
0x0805dfe4 :    mov    %eax,0x4(%esi)
0x0805dfe7 :    jmp    0x805dfec 
0x0805dfe9 :    mov    0x4(%esi),%eax
0x0805dfec :    test   %eax,%eax
0x0805dfee :    jns    0x805e000 
0x0805dff0 :    mov    %eax,%esi
0x0805dff2 :    neg    %esi
0x0805dff4 :    call   0x805e010 
0x0805dff9 :    mov    %esi,(%eax)
0x0805dffb :    mov    $0xffffffff,%eax
0x0805e000 :    add    $0xc,%esp
0x0805e003 :    pop    %esi
0x0805e004 :    pop    %ebp
0x0805e005 :    ret    
End of assembler dump.
0x8072678 :   0x805e100 
Dump of assembler code for function _sendrec_orig:
0x0805e100 :   push   %ebp
0x0805e101 :   mov    %esp,%ebp
0x0805e103 :   push   %ebx
0x0805e104 :   mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0805e107 :   mov    0xc(%ebp),%ebx
0x0805e10a :  mov    $0x3,%ecx
0x0805e10f :  int    $0x21
0x0805e111 :  pop    %ebx
0x0805e112 :  pop    %ebp
0x0805e113 :  ret    
0x0805e114 :  lea    0x0(%esi),%esi
0x0805e11a :  lea    0x0(%edi),%edi
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: This is why Linus hates MINIX.

Comment: @mcandre: holy crap, I would have written my own OS from scratch, too, if this is what most Minix code compiles to.  Is aligning the stack by 16 really necessary for system calls, or is that an artifact of a compiler setting, like `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4 -mincoming-stack-boundary=2` for libc?